# missing module 'formats' error when import pandas.io.formats.excel

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am new to python, am attempting to work with some existing code, but am getting errors due to a missing module.  I am using python version 2.7, pandas version 0.18.1, all inside VSCode.

**problem code is:**

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
```

**Error:**

> Exception has occurred: ImportError No module named formats.excel

I have tried using pandas.formats.excel but then the 'excel' part is missing.  i've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas

Thanks for any help.

Comment: i tried someone's suggestion of "import pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel"  but i get a very similar error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your python version can't support the module. I ran your code in python 3.8.3 and it went well, but the same problem occured when I ran it in python 2.7. Please download the latest python version in the offical website. https://www.python.org/

Click lower left to change the interpreter.

Comment: We should change python version and this solution worked for me.Thank you.